# Объединение 2-ух интерфейсов в один (bonding+bridge+STP) Centos 6.4

Tags: сеть, centos, eth0

Всем привет. Объединил два интерфейса между собой по средствам bonding (mode 5 - отдача через 2 сетевухи). Но есть такая проблема, создаётся петля. Как возможно её отключить?

Написано:

> bonding(объединять 2 сетевухи в один канал) + bridge(объединить их всех водин L2) + STP(отключить один излишних каналов, ибо петля);

bonding - сделал

bridge - буду делать по [данному тутору](http://antizlo.blogspot.ru/2011/09/bridge-centos-6.html)

STP нигде не могу найти

Comment: А вы чего хотите добиться? mode 5 режим балансировки - вот у вас и петля на канальном уровне. Вы хотите балансировать трафик, объединить, или же сделать active-backup? Конечный результат по подробнее опишите, и укажите ближайший коммутатор, если он есть.

Comment: Хочу объединить два интерфейса, что бы вся нагрузка делилась на две карты (исходящий и входящий трафик)

Comment: Нет. На уровне сервера

Comment: Тогда ваще не понятно, какой трафик то тогда, localhost? Сетевухи то куда то подключены? Сформулируйте развернутый вопрос и поправьте его, иначе очень не понятно что вы хотите.

Comment: Сервак стоит у провайдера. Воткнут в их сервера. Весь приходящий трафик оттуда должен идти по двум картам

Comment: Сервак воткнут в сервера? Вы же выше что то писали про входящий по одной сетевухе исходящий по другой, а сейчас про приходящий и по двум картам пишите. Вы кажется еще не разобрались что вам нужно и как у вас все работает.

Comment: где я писал что входит по одной и отдаёт по второй? Вы что-то путаете! Я писал, что нужно отдавать по ДВУМ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вангую что вам нужен такой режим bonding...

> Mode 4 (802.3ad)This mode is known as Dynamic Link Aggregation mode. It creates aggregation groups that share the same speed and duplex settings. This mode requires a switch that supports IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link.

Либо

> Mode 3 (broadcast)This mode transmits everything on all slave interfaces. This mode is least used (only for specific purpose) and provides only fault tolerance.

Просто STP это удел коммутационного оборудования. Нужен для избыточных каналов, как вы ранее уже заметили. Но на endpoint-ах он  не нужен.

Bridge - для объединения вообще не то.

Comment: Так что лучше, вы думаете? У меня сервер игровых серверов + 4 сайта и БД (в которую постоянно записывается информация по сети). Поток трафика - мощный. И нужно, что бы оборудование не отказало в самый нужный момент.

Comment: Если ваш ДЦ или как вы говорите провайдер, поддерживает 802.3ad то это самый удобный вариант. Я  не зря вас просил подробную схему что бы понять какой именно вариант вам подходит.